# Deviare v2 C# Hook API Call and read param

Tags: c#, deviare

I'm trying to figure out how I can read a param. I got the hook working, only thing is that whenever I do this, it crashes:

```
private void onFuncCall(NktHook hook, NktProcess process, NktHookCallInfo hookCallInfo)
    var paramsEnum = hookCallInfo.Params();
    if (hook.FunctionName.Equals("getPlayerPtr"))
    {
        INktParam p;
        p = paramsEnum.First();
        Debug.WriteLine(p.Value);//This line cause a crash
        return;
    }
}
```

getPlayerPtr definition:

```
UINT64 *getPlayerPtr(int Id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should print all parameters values:

```
 private void OnFunctionCalled(NktHook hook, NktProcess process, NktHookCallInfo hookCallInfo)
    {
        Output(hook.FunctionName + "( ");
        bool first = true;
        foreach (INktParam param in hookCallInfo.Params())
        {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
            {
                Output(", ");
            }
            Output(param.Name + " = " + param.Value.ToString());
        }
        Output(" )" + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

It it doesn't work means that the hooked function isn't in Deviare Database. If that's the situation you should create a custom database:
http://forum.nektra.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=7130